# How to execute JUnit 4 and JUnit 5 tests in same build

Tags: junit, junit4, junit5

In Maven projects, I have some existing tests relying on JUnit 4. I cannot migrate them into JUnit 5 for some reasons. I have added below dependencies to run both junit4 and 5 but some junit 4 tests cases are failing even i added below dependencies. Can some one guide me how to resolve my issues

### pom.xml

```
    <plugin>
           <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                 <forkCount>1</forkCount>
                 <reuseForks>false</reuseForks>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/contract/*.java</exclude>
                    <exclude>**/integration/*.java</exclude>
                    <exclude>**/component/*.java</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.spockframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spock-junit4</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-platform-suite-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
        <version>5.9.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-platform-launcher</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.3</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Can you share your full pom.xml please? This kind of problem is often caused by a missing or wrong setup of surefire/failsafe.

Comment: Moreover, your versions do not fit. Platform launcher should also be 1.9.1.

Comment: And, Spock can also run with JUnit platform.

Comment: @johanneslink please check i have updated

Comment: Use either surefire or failsafe and try again. Then show at least one of the failing tests and the full error message.

Comment: @johanneslink sure let me check'